# With Nested Resources in routes.rb with custom to_param, how can Strong Parameters allow created/update to permit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, strong-parameters, nested-resources

I can't find something that'll lead in the right direction. Everyone else's similar issues with nested resources seems to resolve around `accepts_nested_attributes_for`… which I'm not trying to do. I'm not trying to save children from the parent, I'm trying to save directly from the child.

In my routes.rb, I have nested my resource

```
resources :parents, param: :parent do
  resources :children, param: :child
end
```

`parent` and `child` tables both have their own `id` column, but also have unique index on columns `parent` and `child` respectively, which I was to be used in the URL instead of the `id`.

> http://example.com/parents/parent/children/child

This is working fine browsing around going to the `show`, `edit` and `index` actions of each controller.

The problem is there are exceptions *saving* data.

I'm hoping the root-cause of the issue doesn't come down to a field in the `child` table is also called `child` as that's what I've used to override `to_param` in the model and need to keep it that way.

Navigating to the **edit** screen: http://example.com/parents/harry/children/sally/edit and pushing submit on the form, returns this *NoMethodError* exception:

> NoMethodError at /parents/harry/children/sally
>   undefined method `permit' for "sally":String

I'm sure the problem is something to do with how my Strong Parameters line is in `children_controller.rb`. Can I add to `require` a hash of `:parent` and `:child` maybe?

```
def children_params
  params.require(:child).permit(:child, :date_of_birth, :nickname)
end
```

**Update 1 (Added params):** Here are the request parameters:

```
{
  "utf8"=>"✓", 
  "_method"=>"patch", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"fAkBvy1pboi8TvwYh8sPDJ6n2wynbHexm/MidHruYos7AqwlKO/09kvBGyWAwbe+sy7+PFAIqKwPouIaE34usg==", 
  "child"=>"sally", 
  "commit"=>"Update Child", 
  "controller"=>"children", 
  "action"=>"update", 
  "parent_parent"=>"harry"
}
```

Other instance variable in-scope at time of error:

*@parent*

```
<Parent id: 1, parent: "harry", description: "", user_id: 1, created_at: "2015-06-27 12:00:15", updated_at: "2015-06-27 12:00:15">
```

*@child*

```
<Child id: 1, child: "sally", date_of_birth: nil, parent_id: 1, nickname: nil, created_at: "2015-06-27 12:00:15", updated_at: "2015-06-27 12:00:15">
```

Comment: Can you post the params log?

Comment: @Pavan I can't believe I missed that out. Yes sure can, although I'm away from it now for about 8hrs. I'll update my question with that as soon as I'm back.

Comment: @Pavan I've added them.

Comment: Sounds more like a form problem - your code assumes that params[:child] is a hash of attributes, but it's not

Comment: Try changing `children_params` to `params.permit(:child, :date_of_birth, :nickname)`

Comment: @Pavan thanks - that's done the trick...

Comment: I've posted it as an answer :)

Comment: haha ok.. since you asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the problem *did* seem to be because the a model attribute is named the same at the model, which is what the params hash is also called (where the real problem seemed to lie).

All I needed to do was rename the params hash.

In `children_controller.rb`, I had to change:

```
def children_params
  params.require(:child).permit(:child, :date_of_birth, :nickname)
end
```

to…

```
def children_params
  params.require(:anything_else).permit(:child, :date_of_birth, :nickname)
end
```

and then also change the`form_for` my form in the new/edit views from:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@parent, @child]) do |f| %>
```

to…

```
<%= simple_form_for([@parent, @child], as: :child_params) do |f| %>
```

Now, all works well across the board, in both tests and when a user uses the site via the UI as normal.

Answer (score 1):

From the ***params***, you need to change the `children_params` like below

```
def children_params
  params.permit(:child, :date_of_birth, :nickname) 
end
```

Comment: Sorry - I've briefly removed this as the answer as it's only part way there. Changing to this makes my tests (using minitest) work, but makes validations fail when users actually *use* the site.

Comment: @Turgs Please explain it in your post.